# Display: none realmente afeta seo?

Tags: seo

No meu site de quiz oculto cerca de 95% do contéudo (texto e imagens) de perguntas e respostas.

Deixo visivel apenas uma pequena area com uma imagem, o titulo do quiz e uma descrição, e por fim um botão "Iniciar Quiz".

Apos clicar em "Iniciar Quiz", começa a aparecer as pergunta uma por um ate chega a resposta.

Isso pode afetar o site no ranqueamento? pelo fato de estar quase tudo escondido?

Vi algumas perguntas parecidas com essa porém diferentemente dessa, estavam usando display none pra esconder palavras chaves.

Comment: Pelo menos o Google, seu motor atua no Dom da página, no entanto, o elemento invisível continua sendo visível para o Google. Já não sei os outros SEOs, mas não deve ser diferente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os spyders vão ler o seu `DOM/HTML`, e não o seu `CSS`, mas...

Pelo fato de vc estar escondendo o conteúdo na tela isso vai prejudicar os leitores de tela, apesar de não ser possível afirmar que qq `screen reader` vai conseguir ler algo com `display:none` o seu site pode ficar menos acessível para os leitores de tela, o que pode prejudicar sua **nota de acessibilidade**

Lembro ainda que podem haver outros dois problemas em ter no `DOM` muitos elementos "escondidos" com `display:none`, o primeiro e menos grave é o erro de **Avoid an excessive DOM size** vc pode consultar mais aqui: https://web.dev/dom-size/

E o segundo problema é vc cair em alguma política de **black hat** do Google, que pode te punir por tentar esconder `links` e outros elementos interativos com `display: none;`, então é altamente recomendável que nunca use esse  display:none em links

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Vc pode conferir sua **nota de acessibilidade** na aba `Audits` pelo `DevTools` do Chrome, essa nota sim pode interferir no seu ranqueamento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui o reporte onde vc deve conferir essa questão de conteúdo oculto para os `screen readers`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]